# Prove that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<2$ for every n>1 using induction

Tags: proof-verification, fibonacci-numbers

Fibonacci sequence of $a_n$: Prove that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq2$ for every $n\geq1$. I was able to prove this using the base case:
$$n=1 | n=2$$ 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq2|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq2$$
$$\frac{a_{1+1}}{a_1}\leq2|\frac{a_{2+1}}{a_2}\leq2$$
$$\frac{a_{2}}{a_1}=\frac{1}{1}\leq2|\frac{a_{3}}{a_2}=\frac{2}{1}\leq2$$
$$1\leq2|2\leq2$$
How can I prove this using induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inductive hypothesis: $1 < \frac{a_n} {a_{n-1}} < 2$
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{a_n + a_{n-1}}{a_n} = 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}} {a_n} < 1 + 1 = 2
$$

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if we need induction. We see $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{a_{n} + a_{n-1}}{ a_{n}} = 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}.$$ But clearly $a_{n-1} \le a_n$ so $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \le 1$ and we can conclude $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} \le 2.$$